# Actualizar en Trigger de delete en Mysql8

Tags: mysql, trigger, delete

tengo una tabla en MySQL8 y una situación similar a esta:
[image: Ejemplo]

Tengo solucionado el trigger de insert, pero al querer hacer el trigger de delete (por ejemplo) me dice que no puedo modificar la tabla ya que esta bloqueada por el trigger.
La idea es que si por ej quiero borrar el id2, o sea el grupo 9 folio 2, los folios del grupo 9 (id: 3,4 y 9) deberían renumerarse. En este caso el ID3 pasaria a ser folio 2, el ID4 folio 3 y el ID9 folio 4.
Espero que me entiendan.
 El trigger que habia intendado es el siguiente:
IF (SELECT `id` FROM `carpetas` WHERE idgrupo=old.idgrupo and folio > old.folio) IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE `carpetas` SET folio=folio-1 WHERE idgrupo=old.idgrupo and folio > old.folio;
END IF; 
Alguna idea? Desde ya muchas gracias...

Comment: This is an English language site; please translate your question. Alternatively, you can try https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not written in English. The DBA.SE site's language is English. Please consider re-writing to English. Thanks.